# get variables outside of fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Login function where I want to show an alert depending if the login its successful or its wrong. First of all, I declare the variable and after I do the fetch where depending of the result I give a value to the variable.

And after the fetch is done, depending of this value I want to show the alert.
My problem is that the value is undefined after the fetch.

This is my code.

```
onLogin(){
        var a;
        fetch('http://xxxxx/user/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password
                })
        })
        .then(function(response){
        if (response.status === 404){
        response.text().then(function(object){
            var a = "NO";
        })
        } else if (response.status === 200){
        response.text().then(function(object){
            var a = "OK";
        })}
        })

      if (a == "OK"){ 
        Alert.alert(
            'Acceso',
            'a',
            [{
                text: 'Aceptar',
                onPress: (this.aceptar.bind(this))
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancelar',
                onPress: (this.cancelar.bind(this))
            }]

        )}
        else if (a == "NO"{
            //something

        }

        }
```

Comment: fetch is asynchronous. You are displaying your alert before you have received a response from your fetch call. Code that depends on the result of your fetch should be part of the `.then` at the end of the fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. You're re-declaring the variable `a` (removing the keyword `var` in the `.then()` function will keep it declared at a function-level ).
2. `fetch` is asynchronous, so `a` is not guaranteed to be defined at the time you're calling its value.

A slightly better way to accomplish what you're going for is to pass a callback function in to your `onLogin` function (and bypass the need for `var a` to begin with.

Example:

```
onLogin(callback) {
    fetch('http://xxxxx/user/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        })
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        var successful = true;
        if (response.status === 200) {
            callback(successful);
        } else {
            callback(!successful);
        }
    });
};

onLogin(function (successful) {  // call the onLogin and pass in a function as a callback
   if (successful){ 
        Alert.alert(
            'Acceso',
            'a',
            [{
                text: 'Aceptar',
                onPress: (this.aceptar.bind(this))
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancelar',
                onPress: (this.cancelar.bind(this))
            }]
        );
    } else {
        // not successful, do something else
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point of assigning values to a, you're basically redeclaring it instead of assigning a value.
Remove the var keyword in your then() and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are re declaring the variable a

```
onLogin(){
    var a; **Here you have declared the variable**
    fetch('http://xxxxx/user/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
            })
    })
    .then(function(response){
    if (response.status === 404){
    response.text().then(function(object){
        //Here you are redeclaring it. just remove var
        a = "NO";
    })
    } else if (response.status === 200){
    response.text().then(function(object){
        //Here too
        a = "OK";
    })}
    })

  if (a == "OK"){ 
    Alert.alert(
        'Acceso',
        'a',
        [{
            text: 'Aceptar',
            onPress: (this.aceptar.bind(this))
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancelar',
            onPress: (this.cancelar.bind(this))
        }]

    )}
    else if (a == "NO"{
        //something

    }

    }
```